# Login to a site using the cocoa framework

Tags: ios, http

I am creating an ios app that needs to download a html page and extract some information from it. To get to the page I also need to login. I have looked everywhere for some code on how to login to a site using the cocoa framework, but every answer I see only seems to answer half the question. Here is the login site: romres.ist-asp.com. I need some code for writing something in the first field (the other two are left blank), then submit the form and then I need to be able to see the next page. I believe apps like Facebook should use som of the same technology, where you log in to a facebook and then you can see the contents of your profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you want to do is called [**scraping**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping).

Scraping is really easy for sites that don't require authentication, but in your case what you should do is to inspect the **POST request** being made when logging in the site your interested in (try to understand of the service respond) and the POST request made, when already logged in, to retrieve each page.

The purpose of all of this is to have later the possibility to simulate regular HTTP requests that should came from a browser via code.

If you have any doubt ask in the comments.

Comment: Do you know how I can inspect the POST request?

Comment: Just view source in the browser.

Comment: If you're using Chrome this should do the trick http://cl.ly/0o1A1H0o272k3x2E392j